# Using @Value in PersistanceConfig

Tags: properties, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to database config dynamicly in dependence to environment.
I would like to use @Value to get database info.

My Config file is:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "service")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${environment}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("repositories")
public class PersistanceConfig {

    private final String MODEL_PATH = "model";

    @Value("${mariadb.driver}:#{null}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${mariadb.url}:#{null}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${mariadb.username}:#{null}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${mariadb.password}:#{null}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {MODEL_PATH});

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        Assert.notNull(driver, "JBDC driver is not defined");
        Assert.notNull(url, "url is not defined");
        Assert.notNull(username, "username is not defined");
        Assert.notNull(password, "password is not defined");


        final BasicDataSource source = new BasicDataSource();
        source.setDriverClassName(driver);
        source.setUrl(url);
        source.setUsername(username);
        source.setPassword(password);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

During compile time is property-file properly found and variables driver, url, username and password are properly filled.

Unfortunatelly, during runtime @Value doesn't execute and fill the expression into variable (subsequent exceptions is: "Could not use '${mariadb.driver}' to connect").

According another answer here I added static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean, but i had no effect.

I also tried different combination of Environmnet class and PropertySource values but nothing worked.

Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was pretty stupid. 
I had my configurations file in root of project, not root of src java folder.